# mongoose.Schema.isModified is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

'user.isModified is not a function. I keep getting the same error message. And I have no clue where to start tackling the issue.

```
  userSchema.pre('updateOne', function(next) {
  const user = this;
  
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next(); 

  bcrypt.genSalt((error, salt) => {
    if (error) return next(error); 
    
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (error, hash) => {
      if (error) return next(error); 
  
      user.password = hash; 
      next();
    }) 
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe user is undefined can you try it with userSchema.post

Comment: user isn't undefined. I can log the object and its property on the console alright. I can't see isModified functions as options tho. Do you have any ideas on how I could access it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
I think you wanted to do something like:


UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);

      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```